# ANTLR4: ignore white spaces in the input but not those in string literals

Tags: java, antlr4

I have a simple grammar as follows:

```
grammar SampleConfig;

line: ID (WS)* '=' (WS)* string;

ID: [a-zA-Z]+;
string: '"' (ESC|.)*? '"' ;
ESC : '\\"' | '\\\\' ; // 2-char sequences \" and \\
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

The spaces in the input are completely ignored, including those in the string literal.

```
final String input = "key = \"value with spaces in between\"";
final SampleConfigLexer l = new SampleConfigLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(input));
final SampleConfigParser p = new SampleConfigParser(new CommonTokenStream(l));
final LineContext context = p.line();
System.out.println(context.getChildCount() + ": " + context.getText());
```

This prints the following output:

```
3: key="valuewithspacesinbetween"
```

But, I expected the white spaces in the string literal to be retained, i.e.

```
3: key="value with spaces in between"
```

Is it possible to correct the grammar to achieve this behavior or should I just override CommonTokenStream to ignore whitespace during the parsing process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't expect any spaces in parser rules since you're skipping them in your lexer.

Either remove the skip command or make `string` a lexer rule:

```
STRING : '"' ( '\\' [\\"] | ~[\\"\r\n] )* '"';
```